# Active anchor links not getting set properly on fixed nav on scroll/click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm adding and removing a class for active anchor link (color:red). The issue is the class is not being added consistently according to sections and I don't seem to figure this one out.

How can I modify my code as so anchor links get "highlited" when its respective section is on top of the page consistently?

Here is my code:

```
    // for secondary nav
 var topRange      = 200,  // measure from the top of the viewport to X pixels down
     edgeMargin    = 20,   // margin above the top or margin from the end of the page
     contentTop = [];

 // Set up content an array of locations for secondary nav
 $('.overlay-box').find('a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var name = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('#')+1);
    contentTop.push( $('[name="' + name + '"]').offset().top );
 });

// adjust secondary nav on scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      bodyHt = $(document).height(),
      vpHt = $(window).height() + edgeMargin;  // viewport height + margin
  $.each( contentTop, function(i,loc){
   if ( ( loc > winTop - edgeMargin && ( loc < winTop + topRange || ( winTop + vpHt ) >= bodyHt ) ) ){
    $('.nav-bar li')
     .removeClass('anchor-selected')
     .eq(i).addClass('anchor-selected');
   }
  });
});
```

here is the site:

http://www.icontrol.com/what-we-do/platform-services/

Answer (score 0):

I cant see exactly how you are going about doing this.

I have put together a jsfiddle to achieve what you are looking to do

Hope its what you need :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/66ZbB/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass('anchor-selected');
    var obj = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: obj.offset().top
    }, 1000, function () {
        obj.addClass('anchor-selected');
    });
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('a').removeClass('anchor-selected');
    //alert($(window).scrollTop() +":");
    $('a').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).offset.top);
        if (($(window).scrollTop() <= ($(this).offset().top)) && ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(this).offset().top - 20))) {
            $(this).addClass('anchor-selected');
        }
    });
});
});
```